# Переопределение print в Perl

Tags: perl

Есть большой код с использованием FCGI. И вот незадача... FCGI обновился (известная проблема при переходе с 0.68 - который уже требует от программиста utf8::encode). И решение - переопределение функции print, и уже в нем прописать все нужные преобразования вывода. Но не все так просто: казалось бы бери CORE::print и переопределяй... ан нет не получается.

Вопрос не в том, как это решить (решается это через TIEHANDLE), а почему? Чем такое особое исключение заслуживает print в противовес тому же push или chomp?

Comment: voy22, пожалуйста, не забывайте принимать ответы, если они вас устраивают.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html), секция «Overriding Built-in Functions».
Некоторые функции не могут быть переопределены, например, exists и grep.

print тоже из их числа. У нее нет внятного прототипа. Вы не сможете принять опциональный файлхендл как аргумент.

Сравните:

```
print prototype 'CORE::push';
```

и

```
print prototype 'CORE::print';
```

Второе выдаст undef, почему так — [perldoc -f prototype](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/prototype.html).